# Comparing arrays for my search algorithm

Tags: arrays, bash

I've been working on a very common project, however I hit a wall recently and don't understand why my code is not working. I've tried searching online for solutions, but I am new to bash and have trouble understanding what they are doing with other peoples codes. If you could help me get past this I would appreciate it. This is also my first post on this site.

I am suppose to read in a file that contains a list of students and names. I decided this was the easiest way for me to tackle it.

this reads in the file and separates it into two different arrays. My issue is the if statement. I want it to compare the user input with the separated array. If they match then I want them to print out the students name.

```
((i=0))
echo "please enter students Name: "
while IFS=":" read -a fields ;
do
students[$i]=${fields[0]}
grades[$i]=${fields[1]}
if [${students[$i]} = ${student[0]}]
echo ${students[$i]}
else 
echo "student does not exist"
((i++))
fi
done < students.dat
```

Comment: You haven't made it clear what the problem is. But from the code (which you really shouldn't chop up like that it makes it harder to read) you have, at very least, missed the spaces needed around `[` and `]` in the `if` condition. `[` is a *command* not just syntax.

Comment: Ok I edited the comment to make it easier to read the code. If I understand you correctly it should look like this if [ ${students[$i]} = ${student[0]} ] I am testing that right now thanks!

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. It worked just like you said. Wow do I feel silly thank you so much. I literally spent 2 hours trying to figure that one problem out. I also forgot an extra =.

Comment: Better learn the syntax of a language before writing code in it. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html. Also, although I'm personally not a fan, this might indeed be useful to beginners: http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: By the way, I also don't see a `then` in your code.

Comment: There's an issue in your code for incrementing i variable, it's happening only during the "else" part. Considers putting ((i++)) after the "fi" line. Also, "then" word at the end of "if" statement line or first word as in the next line  is missing.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Is there something specific you dislike about shellcheck or are you just not a fan of some of its more "prescriptive" suggestions? (I'm just curious.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Closer to latter I suppose. It's been a while since I last evaluated the tool, but I have the impression that there's some personal preferences in the suggestions that not everyone will agree with. Also, bash syntax is pretty simple. So to a reasonably experienced coder in bash nothing beats good syntax coloring and a clear mind, IMO.

Comment: @4ae1e1 There are some *shocking* corner cases and portability issues that trip up even experienced coders in my experience but yes, many many of the things it warns about are obvious to anyone who has spent real time working with and understanding "the shell".